# Is it possible to obtain Parse User outside of cloud code

Tags: parse-server

I would like to obtain the current Parse user in my index.js (before cloud code is being called). Is this possible?

I know that the current user is populated when my cloud code functions are called but I want to do some custom authentication in my express app but dont see a way of getting the current Parse user. I even checked req.headers and dont see the session token which I expected to be passed in.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Maybe there is a way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish?